# Ethers.js BigNumber mul method returns unexpected answer past 18 decimals

Tags: javascript, solidity, ethers.js

I'm working on a bot that tracks the price of an invested asset in WBNB, so I implemented a function that checks the balance of this asset, then multiplies it by its price. The issue is that it is not differentiating between decimal places:

```
  const tokenBalance = (await token.functions.balanceOf(address))[0];

  let tokenOut = addresses.WBNB,
    tokenIn = contractAddress;

  // 1 custom token
  const amountIn = tokens("1");

  // how much is 1 custom token in WBNB
  const amounts = await router.getAmountsOut(amountIn, [tokenIn, tokenOut]);

  const result = amounts[1].mul(tokenBalance).toString();
  console.log(ethers.utils.formatEther(result));
  // 1680242782775341.15960160560224 (it would be great to have this much BNB, but this is the error)
```

The result is fine, but it doesn't calculate the right decimal places. For example, if I calculate 1% of this amount, I get:

`1680242769310983.64248382760988`

How can I get an accurate result?

Comment: The first thing i see there (not sure if this is your issue or not) is that when you're calling balanceOf it should be `token.balanceOf(address)` i've not see the `function` or `[0]` indexing before. Just a thought